# Sending the output of puts to a logfile and to stdout at the same time?

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I am doing this many times like `puts "$log" "blah blah blah"` and `puts "blah blah blah"`
one for putting it into log file and one for displaying it to stdout.

can it be done in one line or in simple manner just using one puts or in a better way.

Also are there any color code that we can use to output colored text like `tput` in linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're the one making the output calls yourself, create a procedure and call that instead.

```
proc log2OutErr {msg} {
    global log

    puts $msg
    puts $log $msg
}
```

If you want *all* the scripts output to go to both the logfile and stdout, don't open the logfile in Tcl, just pipe your scripts output to [tee](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html) when you start it: `tclsh script.tcl | tee logfile`, then `puts` to stdout.

Comment: this is the easiest way. For your question regarding colors, I suggest asking a different question.

Comment: I'd pass `$log` as a parameter, but +1 anyway